# Verifying Tor source package impossible due to the valid key not linked

Tags: source-code

On the tor website there is a section:
https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/signing-keys.html.en

The correct key from Nick Mathewson (0xFE43009C4607B1FB) is not linked there. However the correct key is listed in the file https://2019.www.torproject.org/include/keys.txt

Could somebody tell me where should I report this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Go to [trac.torproject.org](http://trac.torproject.org). Create an account, then open a ticket.